# UITableViewCell in different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I run my app in the simulator, my table cells are the correct length (iPhone 5s) but when I run it on the iPhone6 the cells start out as the entire width of the screen but then evert back to their iPhone 5s size.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    theTableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) //Don't forget this line

    var leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: theTableView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    var rightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: theTableView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    view.addConstraints([leftSideConstraint, rightSideConstraint])

  }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MySampleCell") as! UITableViewCell


    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.size.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.size.height

    theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth - 20, 44)
    return cell
 }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should never need to set the frame of a cell. It will always fill its tableview. Perhaps your table view's frame is wrong.

Comment: How can it be wrong if I'm setting it to the bounds of the view?

Comment: Why are you setting the table view's frame over and over inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? Set it once in the proper location.

Comment: In viewDidLoad? When I put it there, the cells stay the size for iPhone 5s as opposed to first being the size for iPhone6 and then reverting back.

Comment: Why are you setting the table view's frame based on the screen size? It should be based on the view controller's view's size.

Comment: If you assing your cells background color to be purple you will see that there is a lot of purple to the right. Your cell spans the entire width probably but the content inside the cell is not layout correctly.

Comment: Updated question. I changed background color and as you can see, the width of the cell stops before the edge of the screen.

Comment: You should be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` rather than the version you are using which returns a cell with no size class as it is not part of the table. As you are using auto layout, you should have constraints in the cell which pin it to the edges of their content view. The cell frame should not need set, or the table view frame really. The cell height should be defined in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. Also for cells, it is `cell.contentView` which is the main customize able view and not cell itself.

Comment: How do I pin the edges to the content view? Do they have a name? How do I reference them in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
```

The view's frame should be configured probably in viewDidLoad and typically doesn't change.

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth - 20, 44)
```

If all you want to do is to set the height of a cell to 44 either set the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0` or add the following override to your view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(44)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have the cell fit (width) on all device sizes.

Comment: It does that by default. You don't need to do anything extra for that... If your app doesn't behave that way then the problem is likely somewhere else. Can you provide screenshots that visually show your problem maybe?

Comment: Sure, question updated with screenshot. As you can see on iPhone 6 the cells don't fit the width. But on iPhone 5, 5s and 4 it works just fine.

Comment: You UITableViewCell subclasses are probably not using AutoLayout are they? how do you lay out the subclass elements? What do you subclass' constraints look like?

Comment: AutoLayout is enabled for my cells. What kind of constraints do I need to make cell width fit across entire screen? I can't add constraints on Storyboard...

Comment: You cell width is fitting the entire screen. Your views inside the cell need to be constraint to the bounds of the table view cells content view. Please see Autolayout reference for starters: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: So you're saying I need to fix the constraints for the controls inside the cell? I created these programmatically so I need to do the constraints programmatically?

Comment: can you post example code of your constraints (maybe for one subview only)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87832/discussion-between-theactuary-and-der-michael).

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this loads of time before after screens above 320px were introduced.

Subclass UITableViewCell and make sure that you override

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

In there call super.layoutSubviews() and then read the frame size and resize any subelements in there based on that new frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem might be with the actual `UITableView`. Are you using a `UITableViewController` or did you add a table to the view?

To make your views adapt, you should not use explicit sizes in your code. Set the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints for the `tableView` if you added manually, and do the same in the custom cells you created.

Let me know if you have any more questions or if anything is unclear.